# Can't create recursive type `using T = vector<T::iterator>`

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, types, type-systems

I'm trying to create a vector that contains its own iterators as elements, and I find it impossible to fully expand the type declaration.

```
using MyVectorType = std::vector<std::vector<...>::iterator>;
// Trying to fill in the ...                 ^^^
```

Another approach that fails is:

```
using MyVectorType = std::vector<MyVectorType::iterator>;
```

> use of undeclared identifier 'MyVectorType'
> Trying to use an intermediate declaration also fails

```
template <class T>
using MyVectorType_incomplete = std::vector<T>;
using MyVectorType = MyVectorType_incomplete<MyVectorType_incomplete::iterator>;
```

> error: 'MyVectorType_incomplete' is not a class,
> namespace, or enumeration

Clearly using a pointer instead solves this issue.

```
struct It {
   It *iterator;
};
vector<It>;
```

However this means that you cannot use the iterator interface, and basically have to reimplement the iterator for the given class.

Is there a way to do this in C++?

More generally, is there a way to create recursive types like the above, where you refer to a type before it's created?

Comment: Can you elaborate your specific use cases and requirements a bit more please?

Comment: `std::pair` takes two template parameters. You are trying to pass three arguments.

Comment: _"is there a way to create recursive types ..."_ yes there is in c++, one prominent example is the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I simplified the example by using a vector having its own iterators as elements. It's unclear to me how CRTP would help generate the type here, and I've used CRTP before.

Comment: I find your question to be a bit unclear still. If the vector contains iterators, what will that iterator point at when dereferenced? Another iterator? That points to another iterator ect. The whole concept is logically flawed. You need to give a better explanation of what you're actually trying to do. An infinite depth of iterators that points at other iterators is by definition infinately recursing and can't be done. If that's not what your trying to do then please clarify.

Comment: @super What's wrong with an iterator pointing to another iterator? You could use it to make chains. Plain iterators still support the equality operation.
In my use case I use pairs as elements, that include an iterator to a different element along with other information, and I have the same issue. This is a simplification of this problem.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with it. It's just that if they are all the same there is no end-point. It's just an inifine number of iterators that each point at an infinite number of underlying iterators. Which in practical terms is clearly impossible to implement and doesn't really serve a purpose other then the theoretical aspect of it.

Comment: @super I see. So I understand the C++ type system cannot handle this. Instead I should use `std::vector<size_t>`, where the compiler doesn't need to worry about what `size_t` stands for (which is the index of another element). This sucks for my use case unfortunately, because I want to use iterators to `std::set` elements, which cannot be converted to `size_t` and accessible in constant time.

Comment: I guess I can take the shameful route of using `void*`.

Comment: @Kostas The issue is not the type system I think. The issue is that you are trying to name the content of the container through the types defined inside the container. If you define the types yourself it seems quite trivial to get around.

Comment: The issue is that there's no endpoint. An iterator of iterators of iterators that *eventually* points to something else is great and very useful. But the type you're trying to define is an iterator to an iterator to an iterator ad infinitum. There's nothing useful at the end of the rainbow; just another rainbow.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `There's nothing [useful] at the end of the rainbow; just another rainbow.`
Adding to my quotebook.
@super That makes sense. Something like `struct A { A* a; }; vector<A>` instead works fine. I guess this is why you cannot possibly implement linked lists without pointers in C++, pointer is the only type that allows self-reference without full type expansion (which would fail in the presence of a cycle).
Thanks both for your help.

Comment: @Kostas: I think you're mistaken.  An iterator can be useful outside of the thing it points at. Namely, it's _position_ in the vector, or the _position_ that it points at, may be the useful state. With a vector, this can also be done as `vector<size_t>`, so is pointless, but I could see that there might be some wierd edge cases where a list of iterators to other positions in that list could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible by the standard.

To achieve what you want you must be able to refer to `std::vector<T>::iterator` while `T` is incomplete.

Before C++17 `T` was required to be complete to instantiate `std::vector<T>` at all, so it cannot work there.

Since C++17 the standard allows instantiating `std::vector<T>` with incomplete types `T`, however only as long as the type is complete before any of its members are referenced, see [[vector.overview]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/vector.overview#4) of the post-C++20 draft.

However, if you want to achieve such a recursion, you need to be able to inherit or have a member of type `std::vector<T>::iterator`. Not only does this reference the `::iterator` type, but it also requires it to be instantiated, which is not guaranteed to work at this point.

Having the class inherit from `std::vector<T::iterator>` won't work either, since then `T` needs to be complete. Deferring `T::iterator` to another inherited class will also not work, since the classes then recursively depend on being completed before one another.

Depending on how the standard library is implementing `std::vector<T>::iterator` the following may work, although it is technically undefined behavior according to the standard:

```
struct MakeMyVectorType : std::vector<MakeMyVectorType>::iterator  {
};

using MyVectorType = std::vector<MakeMyVectorType>;

int main() {
    MyVectorType v1(10);
    MyVectorType v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    v2.push_back({v1.begin()+5});
    MyVectorType v3{{v2.begin()}, {v2.end()}};
    std::cout << v1.size() << "\n";  // 10
    std::cout << v2.size() << "\n";  // 11
    std::cout << v3.size() << "\n";  // 2
}
```

I am also not really sure how you would use this type.

Comment: This is really really insightful, thanks!
> I am also not really sure how you would use this type. <
Having a container of tuples containing among others an iterator to a different element is a pretty useful building block, though not sure if it's worth the CRTP madness :)

Comment: @Kostas Note that I changed my mind. This is actually not strictly conforming to the standard, but may happen to work depending on the standard library implementation. See my last edits.

Answer (score 1):

`using` introduces a type alias. An alias is a name of some other thing. You can always replace the alias with that other thing. In fact you must do it in order to figure out properties of types that involve aliases, because aliases don't have properties of their own.

```
using MyVectorType = std::vector<MyVectorType::iterator>; // replace the name with the thing named
using MyVectorType = std::vector<std::vector<MyVectorType::iterator>::iterator>; // again
using MyVectorType = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<MyVectorType::iterator>::iterator>; ::iterator>::iterator>; // and again and again
```

So you cannot have a recursive type alias.

You can create a recursive type, but you cannot close the loop with a type alias. You can do it with a pointer or with a template. Something like this should be legal C++:

```
struct my_vector : public std::vector<std::vector<my_vector>::iterator> {}
```

but I don't know how useful it is to you.

Comment: Your recursive definition is slightly different from what OP wants, I think. The type of `my_vector::iterator` will be `std::vector<std::vector<my_vector>::iterator>::iterator` which is probably a different type than `std::vector<my_vector>::iterator`, so e.g. `push_back` from one instance's iterators to another instance will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on aliases. I'm really surprised we can actually make this work with CRTP, though I guess it's not directly the type we want, but one inherited from it (meaning no constructors, etc.)